# Measure theory and integration textbook

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

What textbooks are good for first course in measure theory and integration? I am looking for textbook with lots of examples and detailed solutions. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bartle, R. G. The Elements Of Integration And Lebesgue Measure https://archive.org/details/BartleR.G.TheElementsOfIntegrationAndLebesgueMeasure/page/n1

Comment: Yeh, [Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Theory-Measure-Integration/dp/9814578541) has very detailed, student-friendly exposition, and there's a [companion book](https://www.amazon.com/Problems-Proofs-Real-Analysis-Integration/dp/9814578509) of problems and solutions.

Comment: You should perhaps describe your background a bit more. And take a look here, there are lots of similar earlier questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measure-theory+book-recommendation